# Process list and map from List<Map<String, String>>

Tags: java, collections

I have something like this `List<Map<String, String>>`. Need to process list and map both. How can I do this?

List of maps:

```
[ {Language=en_US, ArticleNumber=000106422, PublishStatus=Draft}, 
  {Language=en_US, ArticleNumber=000106422, PublishStatus=Online} ]
```

Comment: Can you be more precise?

Comment: Please make your question more precise and post what you have tried so far

Comment: Lokesh can u give any suggestion/

Comment: This is the List of maps   [
{Language=en_US, ArticleNumber=000106422, PublishStatus=Draft}, 
{Language=en_US, ArticleNumber=000106422, PublishStatus=Online}
]  I need to process each map individually and compare the Key ArticleNumber with a String variable

Comment: I need to compare both the maps inside a loop

Comment: Are you sure this is a map `{Language=en_US, ArticleNumber=000106422, PublishStatus=Draft}` ?

Comment: I have a List of maps like this
[
{Language=en_US, ArticleNumber=1}, 
{Language=ja, ArticleNumber=1},
{Language=en_US, ArticleNumber=2},
{Language=ja, ArticleNumber=2}
]

I want to compare each map on the basis of ArticleNumber and Language
eg. If an ArticleNumber=1 in 1st map with lang=en
If an ArticleNumber=1 in 1st map with lang=ja

then the ArticleNumber=2 should have lan=en and ja 
then return me true

Comment: @AkshaySharma it's impossible to read code posted in the comments like that. Please edit your question with the result you'd like to get.

Comment: I have a List of maps  
[  
{Language=en_US, ArticleNumber=1},   
{Language=ja, ArticleNumber=1},  
{Language=en_US, ArticleNumber=2},  
{Language=ja, ArticleNumber=2}  
]  

I want to compare each map on the basis of ArticleNumber and Language  
eg. If an ArticleNumber=1 in 1st map with lang=en  
If an ArticleNumber=1 in 1st map with lang=ja  
  
then the ArticleNumber=2 should have lan=en and ja   
then return me true

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below code for process your list having Map.

```
Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
Map<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
Map<String,String> map3 = new HashMap<String,String>();

map1.put("map11", "map1Value1");
map1.put("map12", "map1Value2");
map1.put("map13", "map1Value3");

map2.put("map21", "map2Value1");
map2.put("map22", "map2Value2");
map2.put("map23", "map2Value3");

map3.put("map31", "map3Value1");
map3.put("map32", "map3Value2");
map3.put("map33", "map3Value3");

List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

list.add(map1);
list.add(map2);
list.add(map3);

for(Map<String,String> map:list){
    for(Entry<String,String> entry:map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"============="+entry.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Hope this helps you.